# PreparedStatement not populating

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have PreparedStatement(ps) below, populate it as shown and when executed MSSQL errors as shown last below.  Of course there is NO value of "TRADEIN" in any data that can be seen.  Ideas?

```
     String update = "UPDATE IM_ITEM SET "
                        + "LST_COST=?, PRC_1=?, IS_TXBL=?, TAX_CATEG_COD=?,CATEG_COD=?"
                        + " WHERE ITEM_NO="+itemNo;

    populate:
                ps.setString(++i, q.get("LST_COST"));
                ps.setString(++i, q.get("PRC_1"));
                ps.setString(++i, q.get("IS_TXBL"));
                ps.setString(++i, q.get("TAX_CATEG_COD"));
                ps.setString(++i, q.get("CATEG_COD"));

    debugged: "sqlCommand" and "userSQL" are still parameterized only
    UPDATE IM_ITEM SET LST_COST=?, PRC_1=?, IS_TXBL=?, TAX_CATEG_COD=?, CATEG_COD=? WHERE ITEM_NO=101316
error:
Severe:   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'TRADEIN' to data type int.
```

Comment: It seems either one of the values returned by `q.get` or the itemNo value is contains the string "TRADEIN".

Comment: @DanGuzman
Believe it is not at two levels.  One I broke it out into assignment across five strings and used those strings to set the parameters on the ps and confirmed before the executeUpdate that all five did not have "TRADEIN" as a value.  Two all five of the parameters are only varchar in the db so it is inscrutable why it is being type converted.

Comment: Try using setInt instead of setString for the integer columns. That should throw the error on the client instead of server to better identify where the incorrect value is being set.

Comment: Why are you using parameters in your query for everything except itemNo? That completely defeats the protection against sql injection.

Comment: @SeanLange
Only for testing b/c that is the only field that could be interpreted as an int.

Comment: @DanGuzman
It seems "unethical";) to change the parameter assignment type especially when I know there is data that is value MSSQL is erroring, but I will do it and report.

Comment: Did you pass in a numeric ItemNo? Since you didn't wrap that in single quotes maybe you have the value TRADEIN as an ItemNo, that would certainly explain the error you are seeing. I would be willing to bet that is the problem....parameterize that even for testing and this kind of thing fix itself.

Comment: @SeanLange
Unseen but no it is a String.  In the db it is a 20 length field width.  Thanks for your persistence with this.

Comment: Then that is 100% the issue. You are telling the engine to implicitly convert all rows to an int. Best option is to parameterize that. Or you can change your query. WHERE ITEM_NO='"+itemNo + "'";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152197/discussion-between-cp-and-sean-lange).

Comment: You are using a prepared statement, where you demonstrate that you know how to set parameter values, so why then proceed to introduce SQL injection in `" WHERE ITEM_NO="+itemNo`? That should also be a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Answered, kindly, by Seanlange in the chat.